# Disable PUSH notification (opt-out) from SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios, sdk

We want to create a setting inside our app that let our clients enable/disable PUSH notifications permission sent by MC (commercial PUSH). We need this because we also send transactional PUSH notifications using another tool and we must allow our clients to enable/disable each type of PUSH notifications separately.

We have checked documentation and we see the following functions: are they the correct way to dishabel notifictaions on the specific device?

a.  Android: [PushMessageManager - disablePush](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/javadocs/7.0/com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.push/-push-message-manager/index.html)

b.  iOS: [sfmc_setPushEnable](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/appledoc/Classes/MarketingCloudSDK.html#//api/name/sfmc_setPushEnabled:)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're basically asking whether or not the documentation is correct as you've already identified the methods you would use to execute your desired use-case.

Answer (score 3):

The docs say yes.  Trust the docs.